# sensitivity analysis on ODE model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a model equation of a kind:

$\frac{db}{dz} = \alpha bw$

$\frac{dw}{dz} = w^2 g $

$\frac{dg}{dz} = g b^2$

I have a MATLAB model that can compute the solution. Now I would like to do the sensitivity analysis with regard to the input parameters and alpha. I really don't know how to begin. I have tried to read some articles but couldn't able to get how and where to begin of writing the codes.

Comment: There are many types of sensitivity analysis. Probably you should start by trying to be more precise about what exactly you want to do.

Comment: For example, how the solution affected by using different initial conditions and also how alpha affects the result.

Comment: Here are some keywords to get you started: Global analysis, Local analysis, Variance-Based Sensitivity, One-At-A-Time Analysis... have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis. There are lots of ways to do this so the answer to your question will depend on which method you want to use.

Comment: for my case I chose external numerical differentiation method which is by varying the initial values y0 by a "small" amount lets say delta and calculate the difference of the results. So the sensitivity is the quotient becomes:  (y(end) - y_varied(end)) ./ delta

Comment: @dbx: I want to learn sensitivity analysis for ODE models as well. (1) Where do I start learning about it? (2) Would I immediately get a sense of which methods to use once I learn about the standard methods? Thanks!